# Windows 10 power user menu Win+X and context menu issues

Tags: windows-10

Hitting the <kbd>Win+X</kbd> brings up the menu as it should; although from the list Desktop, Shutdown, Run and Search are the only menu options that open. The other options click like they are going to open but they don't.

I've done some checking and found the directory `C:\User\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WinX` which houses the shortcut's for the Power User Menu. When I click those links all of them load correctly.

I'm not quite sure what's causing the menu choices from the <kbd>Win+X</kbd>, or if for example I pinned a directory onto the file explorer when I try to click the pin item by right click and then left click the item will not open.

Any ideas or help will be greatly appreciated. I upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10. Thanks.

Comment: @Moab – reinstalling the operating system is always only a last resort and should be advised as that :)  From the answer we can see that it was possible find a way to address the issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my WIN+X menu not open anything?](http://superuser.com/questions/948985/why-does-my-winx-menu-not-open-anything)

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution: **AirDroid was the cause of the problem**.

It seems like the DLL file **AirdroidContentMenu.dll** was causing issues with Windows 10 context menu. I uninstalled AirDroid and even after uninstallation, AirDroid left behind the directory and the DLL file listed above. After killing Explorer, opening a command prompt and removing the DLL I rebooted and the content menu issue was fixed.

The AirdDroid developers [know about this](http://forums.airdroid.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=16011&sid=503e54a919400783a5bb998363a03944).

Comment: I can approve this, asking a similar question. I also found out that switching language packs make a temporary fix. But for a solution, we have to wait for the AirDroid guys to update this issue to oblivion.